# Why PHP substr function returns wrong value?

Tags: php

Here is the example code:

```
<?php

$number = 0130;
$a1     = substr($number,0,1);  
$a2     = substr($number,1,1);
$a3     = substr($number,2,1);
$a4     = substr($number,3,1);
$a      = [$a1,$a2,$a3,$a4];

echo $a1;
```

I got result is `8` why not `0`?

Answer (score 3):

Because `0130` is an [octal number literal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) (because of the `0` prefix), and it's actual value is decimal `88`. (Just try `echo $number;` and see for yourself.)

Therefore `substr('88', 0, 1);` is `8`.

Answer (score 0):

`0130` is an [octal number](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) which value is `88`.
Put your number between quotes (even casting it as a string will cast `88`):

```
$number = '0130';
```

Comment: hi dear , but variabel $number its  get  from submited form how to  convert it into a string?

Comment: Hi @willyw2k, show the relevant code because as I'm trying to reproduce your issue I get the expected output.